# Php URL navigation

Tags: php, url, navigation

I am making a php web application. I have included my main menu.php file on each page. I want to make separate files in different folders. But since menu.php is included in each file, the link to other files in different folders is not located correctly.

So how to make the php server always start navigating from the main project folder so that the link is found properly.
I get the location of home directory using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], but if i use require_once function. Server gives a warning

Comment: What is the warning presented by the server?

Comment: It may be because you're loading the file from an "external" source (via a domain name) rather than an "internal" source. Try replacing `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. If the problem persists, try posting a little more information such as your error and your relevant code/configurations. Also, are you using Apache, NGINX, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as seem you need to put $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] before your pages path,

The root directory of this site defined by the 'DocumentRoot' directive in the General Section or a section e.g.

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/example 

HTTP_HOST

The base URL of the host e.g.

HTTP_HOST=www.example.com
```

Look at [php-include-path-problems](http://bitflop.com/tutorials/php-include-path-problems.html) a small tutorial  about How to include files  without conflicts